# Does collectionwise normal imply perfectly normal?

Tags: general-topology

Is one of the following true?

1. [Collectionwise normal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collectionwise_normal_space) collectionwise normal imply [perfectly normal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_axiom)
2. [perfectly normal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_axiom) implies [Collectionwise normal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collectionwise_normal_space)

Comment: Why do you ask? What do you think?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Collectionwise normality does not imply perfect normality.  An example of such a space is the ordinal space $\omega_1$.

- To see that it is collectionwise normal note that it is countably compact and normal, and all countably compact normal spaces are collectionwise normal (since the only discrete families of nonempty closed subsets are finite).
- To see that it is not perfectly normal, consider the family $L$ of all limit ordinals $< \omega_1$.  This is a closed subset of $\omega_1$, but it is not a G$_\delta$-set.  (In fact, [this previous answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/650072/8348) shows that if $U$ is an open subset of $\omega_1$ which includes $L$, then $U$ is co-finite.  It thus follows that if $\{ U_n : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ is countable family of such open sets, then $\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} U_n$ co-countable, but $\omega_1 \setminus L$ is uncountable.)

---

Perfect normality does not imply collectionwise normality.  An example can be found in

> R.H. Bing, *Metrization of topological spaces*, Canad. J. Math. vol.3 (1951), pp.175–186, [MR0043449](http://ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=43449), [link](http://dx.doi.org/10.4153/CJM-1951-022-3).

Below I will outline the construction of Example H from this paper.  I should note that Example G from the same paper (see also [Dan Ma's Topology Blog](http://dantopology.wordpress.com/2012/11/18/bings-example-g/)) was the first example of even a *normal* space which is not collectionwise normal (admittedly, the class of collectionwise normal spaces was first defined in this paper).

Let $\newcommand{\naturals}{\mathbb{N}}X$ be an uncountable set, and define $H := {^{\mathcal{P}(X)}}\naturals = \{ f : f\text{ is a function }\mathcal{P}(X) \to \naturals \}$.  For each $x \in X$ we define $f_x : \mathcal{P} ( X ) \to \naturals$ by $$f_x ( A ) = \begin{cases}
1, &\text{if }x \in A\\
0, &\text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$
Letting $H_X = \{ f_x : x \in X \}$, we topologize $H$ as follows:

- the points of $H \setminus H_X$ are isolated;
- for $x \in X$ the basic open neighbourhoods of $f_x$ are of the form $$V^x_{\mathcal{A},n} := \{ f_x \} \cup \{ f \in H : ( \forall A \in \mathcal{A} ) ( f(A) \equiv f_x(A)\;(\mathrm{mod}\,2), ( \forall A \subseteq X ) ( f(A) \geq n ) \}$$
  where $\mathcal{A}$ is a finite subset of $\mathcal{P} ( X )$, and $n \in \naturals$.

**Claim 1.** $H$ is normal.

*Proof.* It is easy to see that $H$ is Hausdorff. Let $E,F$ be disjoint closed subsets of $H$. Set
$$\begin{gather}
A := \{ x \in X : f_x \in E \}; \quad B := \{ x \in X : f_x \in F \};\\
E_0 := E \setminus \{ f_x : x \in A \}; \quad F_0 := F \setminus \{ f_x : x \in B \}.\end{gather}$$
(Note that $E_0,F_0$ are open subsets of $H$.)
Define $$U_0 := {\textstyle \bigcup_{x \in A}} V^x_{\{A,B\},0}; \quad V_0 := {\textstyle \bigcup_{x \in B}} V^x_{\{A,B\},0}.$$ Clearly $U_0,V_0$ are disjoint open subsets of $H$, and $\{ f_x : x \in A \} \subseteq U_0$ and $\{ f_x : x \in B \} \subseteq V_0$.  It follows that $$
U := ( U_0 \setminus F_0 ) \cup E_0; 
\quad
V := ( V_0 \setminus E_0 ) \cup F_0$$ are disjoint open neighbourhoods of $E,F$, respectively.$\:\:\dashv$

**Claim 2.** $H$ is perfectly normal (*i.e.*, all closed sets are G$_\delta$).

*Proof.* Let $F \subseteq H$ be closed. Let $A := \{ x \in X : f_x \in F \}$, and $F_0 = F \setminus \{ f_x : x \in A \}$.  Note that $F_0$ is an open subset of $H$.  For $n \in \naturals$ set $$U_n := F_0 \cup {\textstyle \bigcup_{x \in A}} V^x_{\{A\},n}.$$  Clearly each $U_n$ is open, and $F \subseteq U_n$.  If $g \in \bigcap_{n \in \naturals} U_n$, let $n := \min g [ \mathcal{P}(X)]$ be the least value that $g$ attains.  As $g \in U_{n+1}$ it follows that either $g \in F_0 \subseteq F$, or $g \in V^x_{\{A\},n}$ for some $x \in A$, and by definition of $V^x_{\{A\},n}$ it follows that $g = f_x \in F$.$\:\:\dashv$

**Claim 3.** $H$ is not collectionwise normal.

*Proof.* Note that the family $\mathcal{F} = \{ \{ f_x \} : x \in X \}$ is a discrete family of singletons in $H$.  (In particular, for each $x \in X$ it is easy to see that $V^x_{\{\{x\}\},0} \cap H_X = \{ f_x \}$.)  Suppose that for each $x \in X$ we have a finite $\mathcal{A}_x \subseteq \mathcal{P}(X)$ and an $n_x \in \naturals$.  We will show that there are distinct $x,y \in X$ such that $V^x_{\mathcal{A}_x,n_x} \cap V^y_{\mathcal{A}_y,n_y} \neq \varnothing$.  By the $\Delta$-System Lemma and basic cardinality arguments we can find an uncountable $X^\prime \subseteq X$, and a finite $\{ A_1 , \ldots , A_m \} \subseteq \mathcal{P} (X)$ such that

1. $\mathcal{A}_x \cap \mathcal{A}_y = \{ A_1 , \ldots , A_m \}$ for distinct $x,y \in X^\prime$; and
2. $f_x ( A_i ) \equiv f_y ( A_i )\;(\mathrm{mod}\,2)$ for all $x,y \in X^\prime$ and all $i \leq m$.

Taking distinct $x,y \in X^\prime$, it follows that there is a function $g : \mathcal{P} ( A ) \to \naturals$ such that

- $g ( A ) \equiv f_x ( A )\;(\mathrm{mod}\,2)$ for all $A \in \mathcal{A}_x$;
- $g ( A ) \equiv f_y ( A )\;(\mathrm{mod}\,2)$ for all $A \in \mathcal{A}_y$;
- $g(A) \geq \max \{ n_x , n_y \}$ for all $A \subseteq X$.

It then follows that $g \in V^x_{\mathcal{A}_x,n_x} \cap V^y_{\mathcal{A}_y,n_y}$.$\:\:\dashv$

Comment: yes, I have read your previous answer. but now the picture is more clear. Thank you!!