# Question about Urysohn's Lemma

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Can we claim that if $x_0\in{X}$,  there exists a continuous function, $f:X\to [0,1]$, such that $f(x_0)=1$ and $|f(x)|<1\;\forall x_0\neq x\in X$?

Comment: what is your space $X$ and $U$? Does $1\in U$?

Comment: @vidyarthi $U$ is an open set in $X$

Comment: I mean you have to specify $X$, because consider $X=[2,3]$, which is compact, then $1\notin X$ right

Comment: We don't demand anything of the set $U$ (other than being open in $X$), we ask of existence of a function $h:X\to (-1, 1]$ with some properties.

Comment: As @Jakobian , I also think that we don't need more information about $U$

Answer (score 4):

The answer is no, even if $X$ is compact. Indeed, consider the ordinal interval $X = [0,\omega_1]$ with the order topology, which is a compact Hausdorff space. [Every continuous scalar-valued function on $X$ is eventually constant](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/675285/continuous-real-valued-functions-on-the-ordinal-space-0-omega), meaning that there is $\gamma< \omega_1$ such that $f|_{[\gamma,\omega_1]}$ is constant. So if, $f(\omega_1) = 1$, then $f(\alpha)=1$ for uncountably many $\alpha$.

The spaces that allow the choice you seek are called perfectly normal.

Answer (score 0):

Note that a necessary condition is that all $x_0 \in X$ are closed $G_\delta$ sets, because $\{1\}$ is a closed $G_\delta$ set in $[0,1]$ and $f^{-1}[\{1\}]= \{x_0\}$. Tomek's example is a space where this fails for one point.

OTOH, if $X$ is a $T_4$ space (if you want to apply Urysohn's lemma you want that anyway) and every $\{x_0\}$ is a $G_\delta$ (e.g. because it is a first countable space) then such an $f$ always exists:

Write $\{x_0\} = \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty U_n$, with all $U_n$ open in $X$, and apply Urysohn's lemma to $\{x_0\}$ and $X\setminus U_n$ (which are closed (by $T_1$-ness) and disjoint) to get $g_n: X \to [0,1]$, continuous, with $g_n(x_0)=0$ and $g_n[X\setminus U_n]=\{1\}$. Then $$g(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n}g_n(x)$$ is well-defined (a convergent series, with values in $[0,1]$), continuous and $\{x_0\}=f^{-1}[\{0\}]$. So finally $g(x)=1-f(x)$ is the function you are after.

Note that we only really need $X$ to be completely regular and $T_1$ ( aka $T_{3 \,1/2}$, or Tychonoff) to do this proof. E.g. locally compact Hausdorff spaces are Tychonoff, and a commonly used class of spaces.

In summary:

> Let $X$ be Tychonoff and suppose all singletons of $X$ are (closed) $G_\delta$, then for each $x_0 \in X$ there is a continuous $f:X \to [0,1]$ such that $f(x_0)=1$ and $f(x) < 1$ for all $x \neq x_0$.

Comment: Could you explicit what is closed $G_\delta$ set?

Comment: @mathlife a $G_\delta$ set is one that can be written as a countable intersection of open sets; a closed $G_\delta$ set is a set that is both closed and a $G_\delta$ set, e.g. all closed sets in a metric space are like that.